# Up arrow under a sequence

Tags: equations

[image: In a (\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}) document class article, I want the sequence like shown in the figure.]. It is a mathematical expression/sequence/set of numbers with the arrow exactly under any one of the numbers (with or without n= 0). How to do it in latex? Any of the up arrow types (single line or double line) shown in the figure is okay.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically the same as Werner's answer but with some wrapping around it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\underarrow}{\def\@underarrow{\relax}\@ifstar{\@@underarrow}{\def\@underarrow{\hidewidth}\@@underarrow}}
\newcommand*{\@@underarrow}[2][]{\underset{\@underarrow\substack{\uparrow\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\\#1\fi}\@underarrow}{#2}}

\newcommand*{\overarrow}{\def\@overarrow{\relax}\@ifstar{\@@overarrow}{\def\@overarrow{\hidewidth}\@@overarrow}}
\newcommand*{\@@overarrow}[2][]{\overset{\@overarrow\substack{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else#1\\\fi\downarrow}\@overarrow}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
(1, 2, 3)
= (\underarrow{1}, 2, \overarrow{3})
= (1, \underarrow{2}, 3)
= (\overarrow[n=1]{1}, 2, \underarrow{3})
= (1, \underarrow[n = 2]{2}, 3)
= (\underarrow*[n=1]{1}, \underarrow*[n = 2 \\ n=2]{2}, 3)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The extra text can be given as optional parameter. The unstarred version ignores the width of the optional parameter, the starred doesn't.

Answer (score 13):

A simple `\uparrow` can be placed using `\underset{\uparrow}{<stuff>}`. If you're adding wide content, you may want to consider stacking them (using `\substack` - a small `array` structure) and using `\mathclap` (from [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  x_1(n) = (1, 2, 3)
         = (\underset{\uparrow}{1}, 2, 3)
         = (1, \underset{\uparrow}{2}, 3)
         = (1, 2, \underset{\uparrow}{3})
         = (1, \underset{\mathclap{\substack{\uparrow \\ n = 2}}}{2}, 3)
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A lower-level method, adapting an answer by @wipet at [Arrow under text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554923/arrow-under-text), uses `\mathbin` with the formatting provided by `\limits...`, plus boxes and kerning:

[image: limits command formatting]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

%%From:
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554923/arrow-under-text
%\def\type#1#2{\mathbin{\mathop{#1\kern0pt}%
%   \limits_{\raise2.5ex\hbox to0pt{\hss\strut$\uparrow$\hss}\hbox to0pt{\hss#2\hss}}}}

\newcommand\typel[2]{%
\mathbin{\mathop{#1\kern0pt}%
   \limits_{\raisebox{2.5ex}{\hbox to0pt{\hss\strut$\uparrow$\hss}}\hbox to0pt{\hss#2\hss}}}
}


\newcommand\typem[2]{%
\mathbin{\mathop{#1\kern0pt}%
   \limits^{\raisebox{2.5ex}{\hbox to0pt{\hss#2\hss}}\hbox to0pt{\hss\strut$\downarrow$\hss}}}
}


\begin{document}

\[
  x_1(n) = (1, 2, 3)
         = (\typel{1}{$n=1$}, 2, 3)
         = (1, \typel{2}{even}, 3)
         = (1, 2, \typel{3}{})
         = (1, \typel{2}{$n = 2$}, \typem{3}{odd})
\]


\end{document}
```