# Indicate a certain element in a sequence / long list

Tags: math-mode

Let's say I have

$  e \ times \ ldots \ times a \ times e \ ldots \ times e $

How do I indicate that $a$ should be in index $b$ cleanly?

Like this:

[image: indicate element]

I would have put a small arrow above and $b$ if that was on paper. So, I want to see if there is such option here

They say in LateX everything is possible:)

Thanks.

Comment: I only very roughly understand the request. Could you post some picture of what the output should be?

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513452/82917?

Comment: yes. Thanks, couldn't find it before.