# Arrow under text

Tags: arrows

[image]

How to type the following in LaTeX?

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution that sets up a macro called `\placebelow` that, in turn, uses an `array` environment along with `\mathclap` from the `mathtools` package.

[image]

If you want the comments ("Addition in Z", etc) to be typeset using a smaller font, just change `#2` to `\footnotesize #2` in the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap macro
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\newcommand\placebelow[2]{\mathbin{%
     \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}} 
        #1 \\ \uparrow \\ \mathclap{\textbf{\textsf{#2}}}
     \end{array}}}
\begin{document}
\[
  f(x\placebelow{+}{Addition in Z}y)=[x+y]=[x]+[y]
 =f(x)\placebelow{+}{Addition in Z\textsubscript{6}}f(y)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've been around here longer than I have: do you think it's a conflict of interest to mark this as duplicate of [something I've answered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513473/82917) in the past?

Comment: @campa - No conflict of interest at all! In fact, I was quite certain initially, upon reading the posting above, that it had to be a dupe; however, I couldn't locate a suitable posting. That's why I went ahead and provided a new answer. Glad you found the perfect precedent. I've gone ahead and posted a "close b/c duplicate" vote. Feel free to join in.

Answer (score 6):

The solution using TeX primitives only:

```
\def\type#1#2{\mathbin{\mathop{#1\kern0pt}%
   \limits_{\raise2.5ex\hbox to0pt{\hss\strut$\uparrow$\hss}\hbox to0pt{\hss#2\hss}}}}

$$
  f(x \type+{Addition in $Z$} y) = [x+y] = [x] + [y] = f(x) \type+{Addition in $Z_6$} f(y)  
$$
```

Comment: Is it possible to use LaTeX to use your solution? If so, can you give an example of use with LaTeX?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use this solution in LaTeX. LaTeX does not re-define menitoned TeX primitives and the `\strut` macro is defined n all Te formats similarly. And example with LaTeX: copy these five lines to your LaTeX document and run TeX wit LaTeX format.

Comment: Example is: copy these five lines to arbitrary TeX document and run TeX with arbitrary format: plainTeX, LaTeX, Context, OpTeX, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way, with `\underset` (from `amsmath`) and `\bclap` (from `stackengine`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} 

\begin{document}
%
\[ f(x \underset{\uparrow\bclap{\small\sffamily\bfseries Addition in Z}}{+} y) = [x + y] = [x] + [y] ) = f(x) \underset{\uparrow\bclap{\small\sffamily\bfseries Addition in Z\textsubscript{6}}}{+}f( y) \]%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could use an `aligned` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxmath, newtxtext}
\newcommand*{\pluscomment}[1]{%
    \mathbin{%
        \begin{aligned}[t]
            + \\ \uparrow \\ \mathclap{#1}
        \end{aligned}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\[
f(x \pluscomment{\textbf{Addition in }\mathbf{Z}} y) = [x + y] = [x] + [y] = f(x) \pluscomment{\textbf{Addition in }\mathbf{Z_6}} f(y),
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The customary solution  - with `tikzmarknode`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap macro
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
    \[
    f(x\tikzmarknode{a}{+}y)=[x+y]=[x]+[y]
    =f(x){+}f(y)
    \]
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]

    \draw[%
          <-,
          very thin, 
          >=stealth, 
          red!50
          ]% 
    (a.south)--++(0pt,-3em) node [below](X) {X};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should specify that this requires a double compilation.